# Lagging File Dialogs

Tags: wpf, user-interface, lag, filedialog

I have a problem with File Dialogs in WPF. I used `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` and also `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog` in a WPF Application.

In Visual Studio 2013 (either Debug or Release Build) everything runs smoothly. But if a run the application directly (.exe), all FileDialogs will lagging. I used the `Windows.Forms.FileDialog` as well and tried out to outsource the FileDialogs into separated Tasks, but the lags are still there. (Other elements in the same gui are without lags)

The Window which call the FileDialogs has an Viewport3D and maybe the viewport produces the lags?

Comment: Have you tried opening the dialog from a window without a `ViewPort3D`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it in a new window in the same application and also as a new WPF-Project. In all this cases, the FileDialogs are lagging if I run the application not in debugmode.

Comment: I also tried it on an WindowsForm Project with the Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog... Same Problem ?! :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

On both system I tested the application it was running Kaspersky Internet Security 2015 in the background. As I stopped it, the lags disappeared. I'm suprised that this can produce lags about 2-3 seconds to show the FileDialog and also about one second to navigate through folders...